# Ask user to retry only one of his three answers? (java)

Tags: java, random, count

I made a little program in Java where the user is being asked to pick three cards, ranging from 4 to 6. It's a bit of a sloppy code, but it works. Three random numbers (4 to 6) are generated. If the user guesses these numbers in the right order, he wins. Now, there should be an option for the user to change one of his guesses if he did not get all cards right the first time. This should be done by the user by inserting 1, 2 or 3 to retry. There should be no new random number generated. I did not learn this yet at school and did try some searching on the internet. Anyone who can give me some insight in doing this?

```
package cardgame;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class CardGame {

public static void main(String[] args){

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    int[] guess = new int[3];
    int[] card = new int[3];

    System.out.println("Pick three cards with numbers ranging from 4 to 6!\n");

        for (int i=0; i<3; i++){
        System.out.print("Card number " + (i+1) + " (4, 5 or 6): ");
        guess[i] = scan.nextInt();
        }
        System.out.println(" ");
        System.out.println("Your hand of cards: " + "[" + guess[0] + "]" + "[" + guess[1] + "]" + "[" + guess[2] + "]");

       for (int i=0; i<3; i++){
           card[i] = (int) (Math.random() * 3 + 2 +2);
       }
       System.out.println("My hand of cards: " + "[" + card[0] + "]" + "[" + card[1] + "]" + "[" + card[2] + "]\n");


       int count = 0;
       for (int i=0; i<3; i++){
       if (card[i] == guess[i])
            count++;
          }

        if (count == 3){
        System.out.println("Congratulations, you have won!");
        } else{
        System.out.println("I'm sorry, you lost!");
        }
   }
}
```

Comment: It would be nice if you formatted your code when asking questions (you might find your own code easier to read after formatting too).

Comment: Sorry, this is not how SO works.  Questions of the form "here's my code, please change it to do X" are considered off-topic.  YOU try, then explain where you're having trouble.

Comment: "Anyone who can give me some insight in doing this?" was my last sentence... I just want to know how I could do this. I'm not asking for my full code to be upgraded. I also clearly stated that I did some research on the internet already. I have no clue where to start with this part as I have not been taught yet at school. I'm guessing I should use a do/while but I have no idea really...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like this:

```
System.out.println("Would you like to change one of your guesses? yes/no");
if(scan.next() == "yes") 
{
    System.out.println("What guess would you like to change? 1/2/3");
    if(scan.nextInt() == 1 || scan.nextInt() == 2 || scan.nextInt() == 3) 
    {
        int temp = scan.nextInt();
        System.out.println("What is your new guess?");
        guess[temp-1] == scan.nextInt(); // -1 because array index starts at 0
    }
    else
        System.out.println("That's not a valid guess number");
}
```

This is a very basic example. You could make it as complex as you want. For example, by adding a loop prompting the user to ask again if their guess was invalid.

Comment: Hey, thanks! I'll try tweek it a bit so it fits in my code. Looks pretty logical now I see it...